# google code jam 2018 node.js boilerplate

Tags: node.js

Was anyone able to successfully submit a solution for google code jam 2018 in `node.js`? I'm interested in a "boilerplate" which reads and outputs the data.

The thing is whatever I tried, it says "runtime error" w/o any further details so I had to write in another language?

This solution worked for me locally.

Also I converted my solution to another language and it just worked, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in the boilerplate, not in the solution.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function solve(shield, program) { ... }

var content = fs.readFileSync(0, 'utf8');
var lines = content.split(/\r?\n/);
var cases = +lines[0];

var out = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= cases; i++) {
    var [shield, program] = lines[i].split(' ');
    var result = solve(+shield, program);
    out.push(`Case #${i}: ${result === -1 ? 'IMPOSSIBLE' : result}`);
}

fs.writeFileSync(1, out.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are reading from file and writing to file. That's why it works for you locally.

Google Code Jam contest format has changed in 2018. You no longer read from and write to files, but instead should read from standard input and write to standard output. See the [relevant FAQ section here](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/codejam/resources/faq#io). Google also posted a sample nodejs javascript solution for their new interactive Number Guessing problem [here](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/0000000000000130/analysis/0000000000000523).

You can also refer to [my solutions](https://github.com/ecgan/google-code-jam) on GitHub. I got through the qualification round with it. I have also created tests (based on [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/)) for my solution. It isn't an ideal boilerplate yet, but hopefully it helps you to get started.

Comment: Actually, `stdin` and `stdout` are also files. `fs.readFileSync(0, 'utf8');` means reading from `stdin` and locally it worked for me with `node code.js < in.txt > out.txt`. Probably there are some peculiarities/quirks when the code is run on their servers. Definitely, synchronous read of a whole file wasn't suitable for an interactive problem, but I expected that approach to work with other problems.
Anyway, thanks for sharing a working approach.

Comment: @kirilloid, they execute your code on their server with `node Solution.js`. Also, you may want to be aware that they are using nodejs 4.8.2. See their related FAQ [here](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/codejam/resources/faq#language-details).

Answer (score 2):

Reading from stdin was also a big challenge for me when I wanted to participate in the Google Code Jam 2019 using TypeScript. To make it easier in the future I developed [a library](https://github.com/bkolobara/stdin-line) with async await support. Using it you can write "blocking" code that looks like this:

```
// Read 2 numbers from stdin and display the sum of them.
import { StdinLineStream } from "stdin-line";

(async function() {
  let inputStream = new StdinLineStream();
  let [a, b] = await inputStream.getLineAsNumbers();
  console.log(a + b);
  inputStream.close();
})();
```

You will just need to use a tool like [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) to create only 1 file that you can submit to the online judge.

Comment: Really useful library. Kudos for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

In order to give a comprehensive and practical answer I believe a thorough example is required:
Consider the task from Kick start 2018 round H [Mural](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050ee2/000000000005118a).
Down below is my solution which demonstrates how to handle input/output for the particular problem in JavaScript (NodeJS)

```js
const fs= require('fs');

const input= fs.readFileSync(0,'utf8').trim().split('\n').slice(1)
  .filter((_,i)=>i%2);

console.log(input.map((e,i)=>`Case #${i+1}: ${solve(e)}`).join('\n'));

function solve(str) {
    const len= str.length,
          waste= Math.floor(len/2);
    let score = 0;
    for (let i= waste; i<len; i++) score+= +str[i];
    let maxScore= score;
    for (let i= 1; i<=waste; i++) {
        score+= +str[waste-i] - str[len-i];
        if (score > maxScore) maxScore= score;
    }
    return maxScore;
}
```

Notes: `fs.readFileSync(0,'utf8')` represents an input string from *stdin*
and `console.log()` is a way to put things in *stdout* (we can use `process.stdout.write()` as an alternative instead, but I found the use of a *console* object is more elegant and appealing).

Answer (score 1):

Nov 2020

Competition URL: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/

Today I used this, below add 2 numbers:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
var stdin_input = '';

process.stdin.on('data', function (input) {
  stdin_input += input; // Reading input from STDIN
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
  main(stdin_input);
});

function main(input) {
  let inp = input.split('\n'); // NOTE: Non-Windows OS
  // console.log(inp);

  let T = inp[0];
  let t = 0;
  // console.log('No. of tests ', T);

  let i = 0;
  while (t++ < T) {
    readInput(
      t,
      inp[++i]
      // inp[++i], // <------------ NOTE: Enable more lines based on more lines of input
      // inp[++i]
    );
  }
}

let readInput = (t, S1) => {
  let [L, R] = S1.split(' ').map((x) => x);

  return run(t, L, R);
};

let run = (t, L, R) => {
  // console.log('t', t, '    L', L, 'R', R);

  L = +L;
  R = +R;

  let output = 'Case #' + t + ': ' + (L + R);
  console.log(output);
  return output;
};

export { readInput, run };
```

Input:

```
3
1 2
3 4
```

Output:

```
Case #1: 3
Case #2: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Mar 2021 and I'm using this simple structure to get start.

```
function getArgs() {
  const [N, K, P] = stdin.nextNums();
  const S = Array(N).fill().map(() => stdin.nextNums());
  return [S, P]; // Array of inputs [stacks, plates]
}

function solve(stacks, plates) {
  stdout.log(stacks, plates);

}

input = `
Put your test input here
`;

((c,f,g,t)=>(r=>(g.stdin={nextWord:()=>r[c++],nextNum:()=>+r[c++
],nextWords:()=>r[c++].split` `,nextNums:()=>r[c++].split` `.map
(e=>+e)},g.stdout={log(...d){t.log(d.map(e=>typeof e==='object'?
JSON.stringify(e):e).join` `)}},[...Array(stdin.nextNum())].map(
(_,i)=>t.log(`Case #${1+i}: ${solve(...getArgs())}`))))((g.input
||f.readFileSync(0,'utf-8')).trim().split`\n`))(0,require('fs'),
globalThis,console);
```

- Use `input` when running in Node cmd, set `input` to empty string to read from stdin on the competition site.
- `stdin` provides 4 functions `nextWord(s)`, `nextNum(s)` for handling next line whether it is a string, a number or an array of either.
- `stdout` provides function `log` in case you want to print out objects in the terminal.
- Design your method of reading stdin in `getArgs`. **Note** that the function only handles arguments for one single test case only.
- Design your solution in `solve`.